# Oracle random segments select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, analytics

I would like to select the following segment.

```
Random 5500 rows including the following segments:
       Subcategorie (sex): - 3300 men
                           - 2200 women
              Subcategorie (age): - 2140 between 18-34 years
                                  - 2100 between 35-54 years
                                  - 1260 between 55-99 years
```

How could I solve this in a select statement?

Comment: I think you need more explanation.  How do you return a fractional number of men, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you use the word "random" but you have a very precise break down of cohorts by age and sex. A truly random single query won't produce such exact quotas. So your query must necessarily be complicated: you need to divide the whole table into subsets which meet your constraints then randomly select from those subsets. Something like this...

```
select * from (
   select * from whatever
   where sex = 'M'
   and age between 18 and 34
   order by dbms_random.value 
)
where rownum <= 1284
union all
select * from (
   select * from whatever
   where sex = 'M'
   and age between 35 and 54
   order by dbms_random.value 
)
where rownum <= 1260
union all    select * from (
   select * from whatever
   where sex = 'M'
   and age between 55 and 99
   order by dbms_random.value 
)
where rownum <= 756
union all
select * from (
   select * from whatever
   where sex = 'F'
   and age between 18 and 34
   order by dbms_random.value 
)
where rownum <= 856
union all
select * from (
   select * from whatever
   where sex = 'F'
   and age between 35 and 54
   order by dbms_random.value 
)
where rownum <= 840
union all    select * from (
   select * from whatever
   where sex = 'F'
   and age between 55 and 99
   order by dbms_random.value 
)
where rownum <= 504
```

This may perform poorly, depending on the usual factors - size of table, indexing, etc - but it will produce those exact cohorts.

In case it's not obvious, the `rownum` bounds are the number of hits in each age group multiplied by the ratio of men to women (3:2).

Comment: Yes, I used the word "random", because there are 2 million people in the table and I would select randomly the following segments. It will be a selection for marketing.

Comment: Yes, I understand the question. I was trying to point that you can't produce such a precise outcome from a single truly random query.